# fast way of splitting, applying and combining two objects in R

Tags: r, split

I want to split two objects based on a common key, apply a function that requires both objects, and then pass the results back.

The length of each object for any given key (`t`) is not necessarily the same, which means I can't combine them into a single object (well, at least I don't see how to do that).

Some toy data:

```
set.seed(2)

supply = data.frame( t=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,8)) , 
                     p=c(cumsum(runif(10)),cumsum(runif(8))) ,
                     q=c(cumsum(runif(10)),cumsum(runif(8))) )
demand = data.frame( t=c(rep(1,8),rep(2,9))  , 
                     p=c(cumsum(runif(8)),cumsum(runif(9)))  , 
                     q=c(6-cumsum(runif(8)),6-cumsum(runif(9))) )
```

Once I have the data, I want to split it by the key `t`, work out where the two intersect, and return the equilibrium `p` and `q`. A graphical example

```
plot( y=supply$p[supply$t==1],x=supply$q[supply$t==1],type="s",col="blue")
lines(y=demand$p[demand$t==1],x=demand$q[demand$t==1],type="S",col="red")
```

This forms part of an optimisation function, so has to be as fast as possible. I'm happy to use apply, plyr and data.table to get this done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should set the random seed to make the data reproducible. However, I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is the function you need to apply?

Comment: Once the data is split, I'm going to apply `myfun()`. `myfun` calculates the point at which demand and supply intersect in a given t

Comment: `myfun` is a work is progress. but, basically, it works out the intersection, as seen graphically in the plot.

Comment: What if the intersection point is not in the data? do you want to interpolate data or take the the nearest point?

Comment: Bty , The question is intersting. By It is not normal to ask for a faster solution, without providing any first working one? As it is asked it is , looks like do it for me.

Comment: It would be highly unlikely the intersection would be at a point in the data. However, the specific point does exist (though, it may be a vector of points - also unlikely). But, a simple answer to the question: I will interpolate the data point.

Comment: A working solution would be to use a `loop`. But, as this is inside a function called by an optimisation routine, and the actual data is considerably larger, a `loop` is not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` and `mapply`:

```
#an example function
#it could be further optimized for speed
myfun <- function(A, B) {
  coef1 <- coef(lm(p~q, data=A))
  coef2 <- coef(lm(p~q, data=B))
  x <- (coef1[1]-coef2[1])/(coef2[2]-coef1[2])
  y <- coef1[1]+coef1[2]*x
  setNames(c(x, y), c("x", "y"))
}

myfun(supply[supply$t==1,], demand[demand$t==1,])
#       x        y 
#2.106726 2.688992 

split_supply <- split(supply, supply$t)
split_demand <- split(demand, demand$t)

mapply(myfun, split_supply, split_demand)
#         1        2
#x 2.106726 3.161048
#y 2.688992 3.357424
```

PS: If you want to use linear models to estimate the intersection point, you could use data.table to first calculate the coefficients by `t` and then merge the resulting data.tables and calculate the intersection point subsequently.

Comment: I'm not trying to estimate the intersection point directly. Rather, I'm estimating the supply function, and using the predicted versus actual intersection as condition.

Comment: You didn't supply the function when I asked for it. So, you need to continue on your own now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few unknowns in your problem. The simplest case would be if you could have a single `data.frame` for supply and demand (i.e. align supply and demand with respect to t), have `myFun` function which takes a slice of this `data.frame` as argument and returns an object, for which the `lines` method is defined. In this case you could simply do:

```
lapply(split(data, data$t), function(subset) lines(myFun(subset)))
```

Now this is likely not the case with your data. Therefore, the following approach should work for you:

```
# split supply and demand into lists with values of t being list keys
# these splits are independent and are not aligned with respect to t
supply = split(supply[, 2:3], supply$t)
demand = split(demand[, 2:3], demand$t)

# get a merged set of all keys
keys = unique(c(names(supply), names(demand)))
# alternatively consider an intersect, 
# then you do not need to check if both lists have key, but then you just do not know what is left out
# keys = intersect(names(supply), names(demand))

keys = sort(keys)

# produce an empty plot box spanning over the expected total range of data
plot(c(xmin, xmax), c(ymin, ymax), type="n")

for (key in keys) {
    s = supply[[key]]
    d = demand[[key]]
    # if both supply and demand have current key t
    # you do not need this check if you used intersect
    if (!is.null(s) && !is.null(d)) {
        # assuming myFun takes two arguments and returns a list with names x, y
        data = myFun(s, d)
        lines(data$x, data$y)
    }
}
```

If you want a data structure containing (x, y) pairs for all t then use:

```
sapply(keys, function(key) {
    s = supply[[key]]
    d = demand[[key]]
    data = myFun(s, d)
    c(data$x, data$y)
})
```

This should return a matrix (with two rows or columns -- do not have R right now to check), with which you can then just use `colnames(res) = keys` to assign names (or `rownames(res) = keys` respectively

In the simple case I mentioned above, the whole thing with returning such a structure would be even simpler:

```
sapply(split(data, data$t), function(subset) myFun(subset))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I was hoping to avoid using a loop. Given the size of the data (~500 supply points, ~250 data points for each `t` and ~25000 `t`) and that it forms part of an optimisation routine, I was hoping for something much faster (using `by`, `data.table` or `ddply` for example).

Comment: Thanks!! The `sapply` approach should work. If anyone has any faster approaches, they are much appreciated (eg `ddply` or `data.table`).

Comment: For such cases I developed the `inline` package years ago, which allows one to insert C/C++ code snippets directly into R code. These are compiled on the fly and executed very fast :) The drawback: need to know R/C API, need to have dev tools installed (if on Windows)